# Android NDK linking C module with C++ app

Tags: android, linker, android-ndk

This is my complete Android.mk file, when I try to build this, I get a linker problem (see further down)

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

#
# Opus - low-latency audio codec
#

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_DIR := opus-1.0.3
LOCAL_MODULE := opus

LOCAL_CELT_SOURCES :=   \
    $(LOCAL_DIR)/celt/bands.c \
    ...

LOCAL_SILK_SOURCES :=   \
    $(LOCAL_DIR)/silk/CNG.c \
    ...

LOCAL_SILK_SOURCES_FIXED := \
    $(LOCAL_DIR)/silk/fixed/LTP_analysis_filter_FIX.c \
    ...

LOCAL_SILK_SOURCES_FLOAT := \
    $(LOCAL_DIR)/silk/float/apply_sine_window_FLP.c \
    ...

LOCAL_OPUS_SOURCES := \
    $(LOCAL_DIR)/src/opus.c \
    ...

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DNONTHREADSAFE_PSEUDOSTACK

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
    $(LOCAL_DIR)/include \
    $(LOCAL_DIR)/celt \
    $(LOCAL_DIR)/silk \
    $(LOCAL_DIR)/silk/fixed \
    $(LOCAL_DIR)/silk/float

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_CELT_SOURCES) \
    $(LOCAL_SILK_SOURCES) \
    $(LOCAL_SILK_SOURCES_FIXED) \
    $(LOCAL_SILK_SOURCES_FLOAT)

LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_DIR)/include

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

################

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := audio-client-jni

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := audio-client-jni.cpp

# low latency codec
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += opus

# for native audio
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -lOpenSLES

# for logging
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -llog

# for native asset manager
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -landroid

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

To rule out that there's a problem with the way opus is being built I've done the exact same thing using a different build system called tundra and it compliles just fine on Windows using MSVC++.

Here's the linker command and errors (I've formatted the command-line for readability)

```
C:/Projects/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++
    -Wl,-soname,libaudio-client-jni.so 
    -shared
    --sysroot=C:/Projects/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-14/arch-arm
    C:/Projects/workspace/AudioClient//obj/local/armeabi/objs/audio-client-jni/audio-client-jni.o
    C:/Projects/workspace/AudioClient//obj/local/armeabi/libopus.a
    C:/Projects/workspace/AudioClient//obj/local/armeabi/libstdc++.a
    -lgcc
    -no-canonical-prefixes
    -Wl,--no-undefined
    -Wl,-z,noexecstack
    -Wl,-z,relro
    -Wl,-z,now
    -LC:/Projects/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/lib
    -lOpenSLES
    -llog
    -landroid
    -lstdc++
    -lc
    -lm
    -o C:/Projects/workspace/AudioClient//obj/local/armeabi/libaudio-client-jni.so
```

errors follow

```
C:/Projects/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: C:/Projects/workspace/AudioClient//obj/local/armeabi/objs/audio-client-jni/audio-client-jni.o: in function (anonymous namespace)::AuClient::ReceiveThenEnqueue():C:/Projects/workspace/AudioClient//jni/audio-client-jni.cpp:419: error: undefined reference to 'opus_decode'
C:/Projects/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: C:/Projects/workspace/AudioClient//obj/local/armeabi/objs/audio-client-jni/audio-client-jni.o: in function InitializeThread:C:/Projects/workspace/AudioClient//jni/audio-client-jni.cpp:387: error: undefined reference to 'opus_decoder_create'
```

I need a second pair of eyes on this, it's definetly linking `audio-client-jni.o` before `libopus.a` but if that is the issue I don't understand how to modify the makefile to get the desiered result. The opus.h API is defined with extern "C" when included in a C++ app. No luck so far.

Comment: Most likely, libopus.a misses some objects. Try `nm` to check what it exports.

Comment: @AlexCohn how do I run nm? I'm currently on Windows and I haven't been able to get a command prompt up that can run the NDK commands.

Comment: @AlexCohn worked around the issue with `nm` and yor right, I can't seem to find `opus_decode` or `opus_decoder_create` in the lib question is now, why is that?

Comment: I have `toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-nm.exe` under my NDK root on Windows.

Comment: If `opus_decode` is missing from the library, check if all objects for *libopus* got compiled into your `obj\local\armeabi\objs\opus`.

Comment: @AlexCohn Yeah, found it. See my submitted answer, thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @AlexCohn for the assist, obviously there wasn't anything wrong, instead all the source files wasn't included properly, slight overlook from my part.

In my case, I wasn't sure how I should set things up to be able to run the bin util commands, luckily, it's as simple as:

```
"C:\Projects\android-ndk-r8e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-nm.exe" "C:\Projects\workspace\AudioClient\obj\local\armeabi\libopus.a"
```

I just picked what seemed reasonable from the prebuilt toolchain.

With the output from `nm` I could verify that the exports weren't there. After closer inspection I noticed I had forgotten to include `$(LOCAL_OPUS_SOURCES)` in my `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES`. Fixing that, fixed the problem.